# Angular ui - tabs controllers executed multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

When I click on a tab, the corresponding controller gets executed 4 times. Whys that?

E.g. `DetailsPersonController`'s `init` function is executed 4 times. Should only be exectuted once the tab's view gets loaded.

Html Tabs:

```
<tabset>
            <tab ng-repeat="tab in vm.tabs()"
                 heading="{{ tab.text | translate }}"
                 ui-sref="p.search.details.{{ tab.id }}"
                 active="tab.active">
               <div ui-view="tabContent"></div>
            </tab>
         </tabset>
```

States:

```
.state( "p.search.details", {
            url: "/details",
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: "app/modules/partials/p/search/details/details.html",
            controller: "DetailsController",
            controllerAs: "vm"
         } )

         .state( "p.search.details.person", {
            url: "/person",
            views: {
               "tabContent": {
                  templateUrl: "app/modules/partials/p/search/details/person/person.html",
                  controller: "DetailsPersonController",
                  controllerAs: "vm"
               }
            }
         } )

         .state( "p.search.details.details", {
            url: "/details",
            views: {
               "tabContent": {
                  templateUrl: "app/modules/partials/p/search/details/details/details.html",
                  controller: "DetailsDetailsController",
                  controllerAs: "vm"
               }
            }
         } )

         .state( "p.search.details.driver", {
            url: "/driver",
            views: {
               "tabContent": {
                  templateUrl: "app/modules/partials/p/search/details/driver/driver.html",
                  controller: "DetailsDriverController",
                  controllerAs: "vm"
               }
            }
         } )

.state( "p.search.details.tests", {
            url: "/tests",
            views: {
               "tabContent": {
                  templateUrl: "app/modules/partials/p/search/details/tests/tests.html",
                  controller: "DetailsTestsController",
                  controllerAs: "vm"
               }
            }
         } )
```

Comment: the reason might be you used `vm.tabs()` in `ng-repeat`, that is getting called 4 times on each digest cycle..try giving static array there & see what is happening?

Comment: static array does not fix it, still called 4 times

Comment: the controller gets called the same number of tabs that are passed by `vm.tabs()`! Weird! Why?

Comment: because of digest cycle, the number of time digest cycle gets called expression gets evaluated..see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7MhLd/850/

Comment: so how can I fix that?

Comment: Even this executes twice: 
           `<tabset><tab
                 heading="{{ vm.tabs[0].text | translate }}"
                 ui-sref="p.search.details.{{ vm.tabs[0].id }}"
                 active="tab.active">
               <div ui-view="tabContent">{{vm.tabs[0].id}}</div>
            </tab>
            <tab
                 heading="{{ vm.tabs[1].text | translate }}"
                 ui-sref="p.search.details.{{ vm.tabs[1].id }}"
                 active="tab.active">
               <div ui-view="tabContent">{{vm.tabs[1].id}}</div>
            </tab>
         </tabset>`

Comment: if you are sure that `vm.tabs()` are never getting  change then use `::` bindonce directive that will bind value only once `ng-repeat="tab in ::vm.tabs()"`

Comment: Still executed 4 times, also, see my comment where there is no repeat.

Comment: how you are calling init function of `DetailsPersonController` controller

Comment: `(function () {
   "use strict";

   angular.module( "app.modules.partials.p" )
      .controller( "DetailsPersonController", DetailsPersonController );

   function DetailsPersonController( DetailsService ) {
      var vm = this;

      _init();

      function _init() {


         console.log( "DetailsPersonController", vm )
      }
   }
})
();`

Comment: by the way html should be like this `<tabset><tab heading="{{ vm.tabs[0].text | translate }}" ui-sref="p.search.details.[vm.tabs[0].id]" active="tab.active"> <div ui-view="tabContent">{{vm.tabs[0].id}}</div> </tab> <tab heading="{{ vm.tabs[1].text | translate }}" ui-sref="p.search.details[vm.tabs[1].id]" active="tab.active"> <div ui-view="tabContent">{{vm.tabs[1].id}}</div> </tab> </tabset>`

Comment: could you create a plunkr/fiddle of the same..so that I can help you..

Comment: Ahhhh..I should have catch that..:( That was silly one

Comment: Duuuuuudddeeee :D I was going crazy

Comment: Can you give the explanation now, then I will accept your answer

Comment: Check I've added an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have `ui-view` in wrong place, which was asking for tab using `vm.tabs()`.

As there are 4 tags because of `ng-repeat` rendered div 4 times because it has placed in `tab` element which are going to repeat using `ng-repeat`.

As `ui-view` directive renders on page 4 times, that check the browser url and ask for that particular which has 4 `tabs` that why all the controller with template got called 4 times inside your app.

**Markup**

```
    <tabset>
        <tab ng-repeat="tab in vm.tabs()"
             heading="{{ tab.text | translate }}"
             ui-sref="p.search.details.{{ tab.id }}"
             active="tab.active">
        </tab>
     </tabset>
     <div ui-view="tabContent"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution is, take care where to place your `ui-view`. It must not be within `<tab>`

```
<tabset>
            <tab ng-repeat="tab in vm.tabs"
                 heading="{{ tab.text | translate }}"
                 ui-sref="p.search.details.{{ tab.id }}"
                 active="tab.active">
            </tab>
         </tabset>
         <div ui-view></div>
```

I made it using this example and modifying it: http://plnkr.co/edit/efnfjoQ8Hft6AZITCR67?p=preview

```
.state('DocumentoMasterView', {
          url: "/route2",
          templateUrl: "route2.html",
          controller:'myAppController' 
      })
      .state('DocumentoMasterView.A', {
            url: '/detail',
            templateUrl: 'route2.A.view.html',
            controller:'myAppControllerA' 
      })
      .state('DocumentoMasterView.B', {
            url: '/image',
            templateUrl: 'route2.B.view.html',
            controller:'myAppControllerB' 
      })
```

And:

```
$scope.go = function(route){
       $state.go(route);
   };

   $scope.active = function(route){
       return $state.is(route);
   };

   $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
       console.log($state);
       $scope.tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
           tab.active = $scope.active(tab.route);
       });
   });
```

Comment: I couldn't help but notice that the content of the tab isn't actually shown inside the .tab-content element

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete the already suggested solution, moving the ui-view outside tab can create css issues (it did in my case), so the solution is to keep ui-view inside tab and add ng-if ui-view div so that in the result, the html contains only one ui-view div.

**N.B. : ng-if cannot be replaced by ng-show/ng-hide.**